# How to create a constraint validator for generics List

Tags: java, spring

based on the example from :https://www.baeldung.com/spring-validate-list-controller

I wish I can create a `MaxSizeConstraintValidator` but for an interface.

I created a `MaxSizeInterface` implemented by the `Movie class` and updated my validator to :

```
public class MaxSizeConstraintValidator implements ConstraintValidator<MaxSizeConstraint, List<MaxSizeInterface>> {
    @Override
    public boolean isValid(List<MaxSizeInterface> values, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        return values.size() <= 4;
    }
}
```

Unfortunately I no longer call the validator when validating the values.

What am I missing ?

Cheers

Comment: Did you create ```@MaxSizeConstraint``` annotated with ```@Constraint``` too? BTW there is a built in ```@Size``` validator.

Comment: Yes I did. Furthermore when i replace, in the validator declaration, my interface by the actual parent class name it works.
BTW this is a behavior sample, I wish I can use this for some other custom validations.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured it out :

```
public class MaxSizeConstraintValidator implements ConstraintValidator<MaxSizeConstraint, List<? extends MaxSizeInterface>> {
    @Override
    public boolean isValid(List<? extends MaxSizeInterface> values, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        return values.size() <= 4;
    }
}
```

Comment: What does your interface look like? I can't get it to work.